# Clear @ARGV before getting input from <>?

Tags: perl, stdin, argv

I have noticed that the contents of `@ARGV` gets directed to the input of a `<>` command.

If I am going to get input from the keyboard using `<>`, should I clear `@ARGV` beforehand?  Is that the only way to do it?

eg:

```
@ARGV = ();
$input = <>;
```

(I was quite surprised that `@ARGV` interferes with `<>`.  How does that make sense?)

Comment: Use [IO::Prompter](http://p3rl.org/IO::Prompter) for keyboard input that is much more ergonomical for the end-user than plain `readline`.

Answer (score 3):

`<>` means `<ARGV>`. The `ARGV` filehandle refers to the concatenation of the files listed in `@ARGV`. If `@ARGV` is empty, it acts as if `@ARGV = ('-')`, which means reading from standard input. (It's magical that way.) See [I/O Operators in `perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#I/O-Operators) and [`perldoc -f readline`](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#readline).

`<>` is meant to emulate the common behavior of many unix tools (e.g. `cat`, `sort`, `wc`, ...) that read from standard input if passed no arguments, and otherwise read input from all files listed on the command line (treating `-` as a directive to read from standard input as well).

If you just want to read from `STDIN`, do this:

```
my $line = <STDIN>;
```

... or, my preference:

```
my $line = readline STDIN;
```

(Note that standard input does not necessarily refer to the keyboard. You can easily redirect it e.g. to a file: `yourscript.pl < input.txt`)

Comment: If `<>` means `<ARGV>` why does it read the keyboard input into a variable?

Comment: @CJ7 it doesn't, always.  as the answer says, "from standard input if passed no arguments, and otherwise read input from all files listed"

Comment: Specifically: choosing whether to read the files named in `@ARGV` or falling back to `STDIN` is a decision made by the `ARGV` filehandle itself, not the readline operator.